# Dynamically create filters based on object fields

Tags: visualforce

In my visualforce page I am showing various fields from Account page where user can input values and search for matching accounts.
Is it possible to create these filters dynamically, may be using `describe sobject` query. So that all fields come automatically on vf page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do, there are a couple of solutions.

If you want to display **all Account fields** I would suggest using `getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet()` and then iterating over the result in an `apex:repeat` to build you page.

```
public with sharing class SearchPageController
{
    public final Account anAccount { get; set; }
    public List<String> searchFields { get; private set; }


    public SearchPageController()
    {
        anAccount = new Account();
        searchFields = new List<String>(Account.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet());
    }
}
```

Then on your page (you'll want to adjust the 'look and feel', as this example doesn't look great!):

```
<apex:page controller="SearchPageController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:repeat value="{!searchFields}" var="field">
            <apex:outputText value="{!field}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!anAccount[field]}"/>
            <br/>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

You can then use the values stored within the Account object inside your controller to build your dynamic SOQL query for your search.

---

If you only want to display **some of the fields on Account** then I would suggest using [Field Sets](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_editing_field_sets.htm&language=en_US), in which case you need to change your controller to something like the following:

```
public with sharing class SearchPageController
{
    public final Account anAccount { get; set; }
    public List<String> searchFields { get; private set; }


    public SearchPageController()
    {
        anAccount = new Account();
        searchFields = new List<String>();

        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.YourFieldSet.getFields()) 
        {
            searchFields.add(f.getFieldPath());
        }
    }
}
```

**OR**, you can change your `apex:repeat` to use the Field Set directly.

```
<apex:page controller="SearchPageController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Account.FieldSets.YourFieldSet}" var="field">
            <apex:outputText value="{!field.Label}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!anAccount[field]}"/>
            <br/>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Again, you can then use the values stored within the Account object inside your controller to build your dynamic SOQL query (or whatever you're using) for your search.

Comment: So I have the Account object in the controller which has the values given by user. How do I make the dynamic soql query ?

Comment: @vishesh What problem are you having? Do you not know how to use dyanmic SOQL? Or is your problem actually creative the query? You need to build the query as a `String` object and then use `Database.query(...)` to execute it.

Comment: I found the answer to it here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33276/dynamically-create-soql-query-from-sobject .Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into Dynamic Visualforce Components. These will allow you to construct page components based on many varying factors, one of which could be in response to use input.

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Dynamic_Visualforce_Components